# Was it Really Canada Day?

Tags: code-golf, string, internet

July 1st is Canada day (yay Canada)! Or is it?  It seems that the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/July_1) page for this day has a lot of Canada related content, but is there another day which is more Canadian?

Your task is to write a program or function which takes a date (month and day) as input and returns or outputs the number of mentions of "Canada" on the Wikipedia page for the inputed date. 
Some rules:

- Dates may be input in any reasonable format of your choice
- Your submission must pull data from the url `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month_Day`.
- Only `"Canada"` must be searched for and counted included substrings, and only in title case. `"Canadian"` does not count, however `"Canada's"` does count. As long as the exact, case-senstitive text `"Canada"` exists within a string, it is a match
- Contents of the page are considered anything within the corresponding `.html` file (i.e. what shows up if you download as page as a `.html` and open it in Notepad)
- Result may be output to STDOUT, returned, or displayed in any other reasonable manner

Test Cases:

```
July 1 => 34
May 14 => 1
Oct 31 => 2
July 4 => 2
```

This is code golf, so shortest submission wins

(As an unrewarded bonus, I'm interested to see what the day with the highest count is)

Comment: Can the Wikipedia API be used?

Comment: I don't know much about it, so I'm hesitant to say yes in case there is a trivial function to it.  Use your best judgement and if it makes it too easy please abstain

Comment: So references to [Canadaville](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadaville), [Canadair](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair), [Canadarm](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadarm), [Canadaga](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadaga), [Canadarago](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadarago_Lake), [Canaday](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canaday_Station), [Canadaspis](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadaspis), et al. count?

Comment: @msh210, Yep, that they do

Comment: Everyone is using enwp.org in here

Comment: July 1 is the day with the highest count! Wrote a quick program for it, though it isn't golfed.

Comment: @MatthewRoh, yes, but that redirects to the required url, so I'm allowing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 31 bytes

```
/jk'+"http://enwp.org/"z"Canada
```

Does not work on the online implementation, the server disables Internet access. I wanted to use http://wki.pe/July_1 but sadly it's a client-side redirect so it fetches the wrong page. The input format is `July_1`.

The code is basically just:

```
"".join(open("http://enwp.org/"+input())).count("Canada")
```

Answer (score 24):

## Bash, <strike>43</strike> <strike>42</strike> 40 bytes

```
curl -L enwp.org/$@|grep -o Canada|wc -l
```

Uses `curl`, `grep`, and `wc` to count occurrences of "Canada" in specified webpage. Like the other answers, input is given in the format `July_1`. This is my first time posting on the Code Golf SE and I'm not quite familiar with all of the rules. Any feedback would be most welcome.

*Didn't realize that output to* `STDERR` *is traditionally ignored. Thanks for the 3 bytes, [Dennis](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)!*

Comment: But wouldn't `curl -sL` still be shorter than `wget -qO-`?

Comment: [Output to STDERR is ignored by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781), so you can use `curl` without `-s` (or `wget` without `-q`).

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! I didn't know that `STDERR` is ignored. Much appreciated.

Comment: @kundor That's a good point. For some reason, combining the two flags never occurred to me. Still, since output to `STDERR` is ignored by default, it'd be shorter to omit the `-s` entirely.

Answer (score 15):

## Perl 5, 39 bytes

38 bytes, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `-e`

```
$_=()=`curl -L enwp.org/$_`=~/Canada/g
```

Takes input like `July_1`.

Thanks to [busukxuan](/users/49362/busukxuan) for saving me seven bytes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with curl, but is it possible to save the six bytes of "http://"?

Comment: @busukxuan, yep, many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3.5, <s>117</s> <s>111</s> <s>98</s> 90 bytes

(*-8 bytes (`98 -> 90`) thanks to [alexwlchan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13285/alexwlchan)*)

```
from urllib.request import*
lambda i:urlopen('http://enwp.org/'+i).read().count(b"Canada")
```

Simply uses Python's built-in "urllib" library to fetch HTML data and then counts the occurrences of the word "Canada" in that data. Will try and golf more over time where and when I can. Call it by renaming the `lambda` function to anything and then calling that name like a normal function wrapped in `print()`. For instance, if the function were named `H`, then you would call it like `print(H(Month_Day))`.

Comment: I think you can save eight characters by replacing `.decode().count("Canada")` with `.count(b"Canada")`.

Comment: @alexwlchan Yes, you are right. Thanks! :)

Comment: Surely this would be shorter in Python 2, since the [`urllib.urlopen` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) isn't in a subpackage (`from urllib import*` versus `from urllib.request import*`), and the `b"Canada"` could be replaced with `"Canada"` since Python 2's strings are bytes by default. I count 81 bytes in Python 2, and it works according to my testing.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 60 bytes

```
Import["http://enwp.org/"<>#,"Source"]~StringCount~"Canada"&
```

Anonymous function. Similarly to the Perl 5 solution, takes input like `July_1`.

Comment: Just to close the loop, this use of the API is totally fine

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 85 bytes

```
return Regex.Matches(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://enwp.org/"+d),"Canada").Count;
```

Takes input `d` like `July_1`.

And `July_1` *is* truly Canada Day, having the most references. With `February_1` and `April_23` sharing 2nd place with 18 `"Canada"`s each.

## Find `"Canada"` day (in parallel), 207 bytes:

```
return Enumerable.Range(0,366).Select(i=>new DateTime(8,1,1).AddDays(i).ToString("MMMM_d")).AsParallel().OrderBy(d=>Regex.Matches(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://enwp.org/"+d),"Canada").Count).Last();
```

(Year 8 is the leap year with the shortest representation). Potentially inefficient, in that the `OrderBy` probably generates >366 web calls, but just going for shorter and appears to complete in not much more time.

Answer (score 5):

## PowerShell, 52 bytes

```
((iwr enwp.org/$($args[0]))-csplit"Canada").length-1
```

- Input as `July_1`.
- `iwr` is short for `Invoke-WebRequest`.
- `$($args[0])` is first command line argument. Start script as `OhCanada.ps1 July_1`.
- `-csplit` is case sensitive split.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <strike>99</strike> 96 bytes

<strike>x=function(d){p=readLines(paste0("http://enwp.org/",d));sum(nchar(p)-nchar(gsub("Canada","",p)))/6}</strike>

```
d=scan(,"");p=readLines(paste0("http://enwp.org/",d));sum(nchar(p)-nchar(gsub("Canada","",p)))/6
```

This takes input d in the form "July_1" and returns the count of Canadas. It counts the words by counting the number of characters on the page, then removes the word Canada from the page and counts the characters again. The number of times Canada shows up is the difference in these counts divided by the number of letters in Canada, 6.

edit: I appreciate the tip below about replacing my function with scan.

Comment: I think you can drop the `x=function(d){` and replace with `d=scan(,'')` making it program instead of function and saving some bytes.

Comment: Thanks! That saved three bytes. I haven't used scan before.

Answer (score 4):

## ES6, 89 bytes

```
d=>fetch('http://enwp.org/'+d).then(r=>r.text().then(t=>alert(t.split`Canada`.length-1)))
```

Sadly Unwrapping all the promises penalises the size :/

Comment: Nice answer, welcome to the site!

Comment: Couple comments. You can apply the same "input is in the format `July_1`" trick as the rest of the questions to save a few bytes. You also have an error using `split().length()`, which will give you a response greater than the goal.

Comment: Agree with @IvanSanchez on the input format and needing a `-1` after the `.length`, but you can save some bytes by omitting the `https:` part of the URL, and use `split'Canada'` (but with backticks!) instead of `split('Canada')` to save a couple more!

Comment: Wow had no idea about backticks! I have made the changes mentioned.

Comment: Firefox allows you to drop the `//` after `http`.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 71 bytes

```
#(count(re-seq #"Canada"(slurp(str"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"%))))
```

Yeah, it would be nice to use `http://enwp.org` but I guess `slurp` does not handle redirects(?).  Anonymous function which take day in the format "July_1".

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby + curl, 44 bytes

```
p`curl -L enwp.org/#$_`.scan(/Canada/).size
```

`ruby -n` + 43 bytes. Takes input like `July_1`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 65 bytes

```
echo substr_count(file_get_contents('http://enwp.org'),'Canada');
```